# Need to update Xampp php 7.3 to 7.4. Shows Apache error

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I need Xampp for Windows 32 bit with a php version of at least 7.4.  I can only find a php version 7.3 which is too low.  So I need to upgrade it.

I downloaded vc15 x86 threadsafe/zip from, php.net.  I extracted it.  Renamed xampp\php to xammp\php-old.  I then copied php.ini-development to php.ini and made all the changes to php.ini as per this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ir_ZewB_PHY

I restarted Xampp but its giving the error message:  Error:  Apache shut down unexpectedly.  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies..."

I dont have Skype/ Team Viewer or Anydesk open.

I changed the port settings of the httpd.conf File to listen to port 8080 instead of port 80.  In http-ssl.conf I changed listen 443 to listen 4433.

I restarted Xampp but I'm still having errors.  The Apache (error.log) reflects there errors.

[Wed Aug 24 12:39:53.747228 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 4220:tid 460] AH01909: [www.example.com:443:0](http://www.example.com:443:0) server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Aug 24 12:39:53.922456 2022] [core:warn] [pid 4220:tid 460] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Aug 24 12:39:53.922456 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 4220:tid 460] AH01909: [www.example.com:443:0](http://www.example.com:443:0) server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
[Wed Aug 24 12:39:53.938089 2022] [:emerg] [pid 4220:tid 460] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting

I really dont know how to solve this and support will be greatly appreciated.  My os is Windows 10 32 bit.   I was told my laptop cant be upgraded to 64 bit.

Many thanks in advance.

**Edit 24 August 2022 !7h30 Johannesburg**

I checked PHP module lines in my httpd-xamp.conf is correct.

`LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/php7ts.dll"`
`LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/libpq.dll"`
`LoadModule php7_module "C:/xampp/php/php7apache2_4.dll"

I ran httpd.exe -t from the windows command prompt it it shows that the syntax is OK.

I ran httpd.exe -v and it shows Server version: Apache/2.4.38 (Win32)

Comment: `7.3 to 7.3`...are you sure? Always proof-read your questions :-)

Comment: _"I restarted Xampp but I'm still having errors"_ - to be more precise, you have _warnings_ now. And those should not stop Apache from starting ... So what is the actual problem now at this point?

Comment: If I type http://localhost in my browser I get an error "This site can't be reached

Comment: Since you changed from the default port (80) to 8080, you need to access the site through: `http://localhost:8080`. If you just do `http://localhost` without a specific port number, it will assume you meant port 80.

Comment: http://localhost:8080 is also reflect "The site can't be reached.  Could it be because Xammp isn't starting up?

Comment: When I start MySQL in Xampp it shows MySql is running on port 3306 but when I I try to start Apache is shows:  13:37:08  [Apache]  Status change detected: running 13:37:09  [Apache]  Status change detected: stopped
13:37:09  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
13:37:09  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
13:37:09  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
13:37:09  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
13:37:09  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
13:37:09  [Apache]  If ...